# How to fetch a collection from a path like "users/:userId/roles" where :userId is dynamic

Tags: rest, backbone.js

Backbone can fetch a model by ID, but what if I want to fetch a collection based on a resouce ID, for example `"api/users/:userId/roles/"` where `:userId` is dynamic. **How do I implement this in Backbone?** I don't want to populate the `userModel.roles` property for every model in the collection fetched from `api/users/`

Comment: You can provide a function to fetch instead of a string and then dynamically create your fetch url based on whatever criteria you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Roles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function(){
        var url = '/api/users/' + this.user.id + '/roles';
        return url;
    }
});
```

That's the bare minimum, assuming your User model is a property on the Roles collection. I'd consider looking into abstracting relations away into a `AssociatedModel` and `AssociatedCollection`, or looking into the [many Backbone plugins available](http://backplug.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Many backbone *properties* can take a function instead of a string which allows you to be more flexible if you need to be. If you look at the example for `url` in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) you'll see an example of that

```
// Or, something more sophisticated:

var Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
    return this.document.url() + '/notes';
  }
});
```

In your case you would probably want something like the following

```
url: function () {
    //myUserID should probably be coming from your model or somewhere
    return 'api/users/' + myUserID + '/roles/'; 
}
```